# OpenShift build from git repo

Tags: git, openshift-origin

I am trying to initialise an OpenShift build from a git repository using an ssh-key as as secret:

```
$ oc new-build --name=modelingweb git@bitbucket.org:genettasoft/gs_modelling_web.git --build-secret deploymentkey
```

But it seems like my git url is not recognised as a git url:

```
error: no match for "git@bitbucket.org:genettasoft/gs_modelling_web.git"

The 'oc new-build' command will match arguments to the following types:

  1. Images tagged into image streams in the current project or the 'openshift' project
     - if you don't specify a tag, we'll add ':latest'
  2. Images in the Docker Hub, on remote registries, or on the local Docker engine
  3. Git repository URLs or local paths that point to Git repositories

--allow-missing-images can be used to force the use of an image that was not matched

See 'oc new-build -h' for examples.
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Can you give this a try with OpenShift Origin v3.6.x ? It looks like both issues have been corrected in the newest version. You can download the newest version here: https://github.com/openshift/origin/releases